# Get UI element value into another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using a third party library which I'm overriding one of its methods

Below is the class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //other unrelated code

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Log.d("Device Number","Device number: " + prefs.getString("devicePhoneNumber", "DEFAULT"));
    }

}
```

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to set "devicePhoneNumber" in the MainActivity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //other unrelated code


    Log.d("test", fromField.getText().toString());

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    prefs.edit().putString("devicePhoneNumber", fromField.getText().toString());
    prefs.edit().commit();

    BroadcastUtils.sendExplicitBroadcast(this, new Intent(), "test action");
}
```

The app always prints "DEFAULT" on the following line `Log.d("Device Number","Device number: " + prefs.getString("devicePhoneNumber", "DEFAULT"));`

Any idea how I can successfully pass  settings set on the main layout to different classes?

Answer (score 0):

Calling prefs.edit() has following impact:

> Creates **a new Editor** for these preferences, through which you can make modifications to the data in the preferences and atomically commit those changes back to the SharedPreferences object

So in our code Instead of:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
prefs.edit().putString("devicePhoneNumber", fromField.getText().toString());
prefs.edit().commit();
```

You must do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("devicePhoneNumber",  fromField.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
```

This will save your data correctly since only one instance of Editor will be used.

If you are intending to pass the data between activites then consider using [Intent.putExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for primitive data. You can also consider using [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for objects.